# initialisation list in c++

Tags: c++

I barely know c++.Not an expert.

I am looking through an already existing code.
I could not able to understand this following code.

```
typedef enum
{
    eEvent_MsgOk,            
    eEvent_InvalidMsgId,    
    eEvent_Failure,          
} eEventType;

class Rs232Event
{
public:
    Rs232Msg*     m_pMsg;    
    eEventType     m_eEvent;   

}
Rs232Event::Rs232Event(eEventType eEvent,Rs232Msg* pMsg)
 :  m_pMsg(pMsg), m_eEvent(eEvent)
{
    // not implemented on purpose
}
```

Here using the initialisation list they are intialising the values.

But the Rs232Msg class doesnt have a single parameterised constructor.

But its having a constructor which accepts 4 parameters.

I could not identify how its getting invoked.But the code runs without any error.

Comment: Thanks all for explaining me about it.But m_eEvent is not a pointer.Its a enum variable.Here like the same as you all told me the variable eEvent is copied onto the m_eEvent.Is what i'm thinking is correct?

Comment: enums in C++ are just integral values.  `m_eEvent` in your case is just value-initialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`m_pMsg` isn't an `Rs232Msg` class.  Rather, its a *pointer* to an `Rs232Msg` class.  All that is being copied is a pointer to an already-existing instance of that class, so the constructor isn't being invoked here.

Answer (score 1):

`m_pMsg` and `pMsg` are pointers to `Rs232Msg`, so the `Rs232Msg` constructor isn't being invoked; you're just storing a pointer to a preexisting instance.